# jQuery UI draggable limitation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery UI draggable module and I want to do one simple thing but I cannot find any help using Google(maybe I searching wrong). This is my code:

```
 $("#table").draggable({
     axis: "x",
     drag: function() {
         if(parseInt($(this).css("left")) <= 0)
         {
             return false;
         }   
     }   
 });
```

As you could except I want to prevent dragable element of reaching CSS left value lower than 0. But this code doesn't work - if I drag element beyond CSS left 0 it blocks. Could you help me?

**UPDATE:**

@VisioN thank you for your help. Now everything is working as I want. Here is my final code. Maybe it helps sonmeone:

```
var table_dim = [1898, 1024];
width = Math.round((table_dim[0]/table_dim[1])*$(window).height());
height = $(window).height();
$(document.createElement("img"))
    .attr("src", "images/table.png")
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("id", "table")
    .css(
        {"display": "block",
         "position": "absolute",
         "left" : -((width-$(window).width())/2)+"px",
         "z-index": "-9999"
    })  
    .appendTo("body");


$("#table").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.offset.left < $(window).width()-width) {
            $(this).data('draggable').position.left = $(window).width()-width;
        } else if(ui.offset.left > 0)
        {   
            $(this).data('draggable').position.left = 0;
        }   
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`containment`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) option instead?

```
$("#table").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: "document"
});​
```

As containment value you can use `'parent'`, `'document'`, `'window'` or `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bAffp/

**UPDATE.** The other option is to correct internal values while dragging.

```
$("#table").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.offset.left < 0) {
            $(this).data('draggable').position.left = 0;
        }
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bAffp/3/

Comment: Your solution has one disadvantage. I'm loosing smoothness. Here you can saw result of setting  containment: "document": http://212.85.103.177/MM_Virutal_Table/

Comment: @SzymonOlewniczak Can't feel the drawback, since the image is too big for my resolution :)

Comment: Wait a moment I will record a movie which will show the drawback.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

$("#draggable").draggable({

limit: {top: 50, left: 100, bottom: 200, right: 200}

});

link is

http://jsfiddle.net/bAffp/2/